# [javascript ]how can I pickup object-like string from my String using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a string like this :

```
"{tagName=input, type=radio,}, {}, {tagName=input, type=radio, labelName=option31}"
```

How can I pickup 3 objects in that ?

thank you for help !

Comment: where do you get this string?

Comment: This seems incredibly easy, just match `{` followed by a string of non-`}` characters, followed by `}`. What part of that are you having trouble with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can split this text like this:

```
var text = "{tagName=input, type=radio,}, {}, {tagName=input, type=radio, labelName=option31}";
text = text.replace(/}/g,"}}");
var res = text.split("},");
```

First line is used for add a "}" at the end of each object you want for do the split without problems like the comma at the end of the first object you want.

Then, in res you have an array with the three objects you want

Regards.

Comment: awesome! Thank you very much !

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark this post as correct answer.